# drop 0 from md5() PHP if byte representation is less than 0x10

Tags: php, md5

Using md5() function in PHP directly gives me the String. What I want to do before saving the string in the database is remove zeroes 0 if any in the byte representation of that hex and that byte representation is < 0x10 and then save the string in the database.

How can I do this in PHP?

MD5 - PHP  - Raw Value - catch12 - 214423105677f2375487b4c6880c12ae - This is what I get now. Below is the value that I want the PHP to save in the database.

MD5 - Raw Value - catch12 - 214423105677f2375487b4c688c12ae

Wondering why? The MD5 code I have in my Android App for Login and Signup I did not append zeroes for the condition `if ((b & 0xFF) < 0x10) hex.append("0");` Works fine. But the Forgot Password functionality in the site is PHP which is when the mismatch happens if the user resets password. JAVA code below.

```
byte raw[] = md.digest();  
StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
for (int i=0; i<raw.length; i++)
hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & raw[i]));
v_password = hexString.toString();
```

Any help on the PHP side so that the mismatch does not happen would be very very helpful. I can't change the App code because that would create problems for existing users.

Thank you.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @yan otherwise the MD5 generated by the Java code from the App and the PHP will be a mismatch and users won't be able to log in. I know it's stupid of me not to append the 0 in the App.

Comment: I would actually try fixing this the proper way. First, fix the Java code. Then, have PHP send the password hash as a proper 32 byte MD5 string. When checking it against the password, if the stored password is less than 32 characters, change the hash PHP sent according to one of the answers below. If the hash matches, update the hash in the database to the proper 32 char one. Over time, this will correct all of your password hashes and you can put the entire thing behind you.

Comment: @konforce I think this is a real good way to fix the whole thing which is what I am probably going to do. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the "normal" MD5 hash to this function.  It will parse it into the individual byte pairs and strip leading zeros.

EDIT: Fixed a typo

```
function convertMD5($md5)
{
    $bytearr = str_split($md5, 2);
    $ret = '';

    foreach ($bytearr as $byte)
        $ret .= ($byte[0] == '0') ? str_replace('0', '', $byte) : $byte;

    return $ret;
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want zero-bytes completely stripped (if you want 0x00 to be '0'), use this version:

```
function convertMD5($md5)
{
    $bytearr = str_split($md5, 2);
    $ret = '';

    foreach ($bytearr as $byte)
        $ret .= ($byte[0] == '0') ? $byte[1] : $byte;

    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: @Unsigned Code labs I need the 0s to be stripped out only when the byte is < 0x10 not all zeroes. will I be able to do the compare here?

Comment: Yes, notice how we only strip the 0s if the leading digit is zero.  If the first digit is zero, it MUST be less than 0x10.

Comment: Thanks so much @Unsigned Code labs let me try this out.

Comment: @Aakash: If the value is >= 0x10 then it won't have a leading 0.  A leading 0 implies that the byte is < 0x10.

Comment: @GigaWatt Sorry I overlooked it. Thanks.

Comment: Added a second version that won't completely strip double-zeros (0x00) bytes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$md5 = md5('catch12');
$new_md5 = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < 32; $i += 2)
{
  if ($md5[$i] != '0') $new_md5 .= $md5[$i];
  $new_md5 .= $md5[$i+1];
}

echo $new_md5;
```

Comment: this will take out all 0s from the string.

Comment: @Aakash, no it won't. It only removes the ones on even positions `($i==0,2,4,6)`.

Comment: @Unsigned Code labs, I assume `0x00` == `0`, given the Java code he has provided.

Comment: Actually, you're right, I got hung up on his words, not his code: "remove zeroes 0 if any in the byte representation of that hex and that byte representation is < 0x10"

Answer (score 0):

To strip leading zeros (00->0, 0a->a, 10->10)

```
function stripZeros($md5hex) {
  $res =''; $t = str_split($md5hex, 2);
  foreach($t as $pair) $res .= dechex(hexdec($pair));
  return $res;  
  }
```

To strip leading zeros & zero bytes (00->nothing, 0a->a, 10->10)

```
function stripZeros($md5hex) {
  $res =''; $t = str_split($md5hex, 2);
  foreach($t as $pair)  {
    $b = dechex(hexdec($pair));
    if ($b!=0) $res .= $b;
    }
  return $res;  
  }
```